# Redirect non-existent url to home in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

A client has seen a non-existent page show up in Google Analytics and would like it redirected to the home page. I am new to CodeIgniter.

I don't see an .htaccess file in this project in the root directory, and tried the following in the routes.ph but it did not work. Do I need to add something in routes.php?

$route['strangepage'] = 'Home';

Comment: Going to need a bit more context but generally yes what you are saying is correct. If it is a non-existent page then the default 404 page from CI should be showing up. So I am not sure how your ga tracking code is even on that page unless you've got a custom 404 with tracking. Also, sites tend to get a ton of calls to non-existent pages from spiders, do you plan on doing this for every 404?

Comment: Thanks @Alex . After looking more into it, it appears that any ending on the url (eg. v31, v100, etc) remains in the url, but is showing the home page. I am still wrapping my head around CI. This is in routes.php: `$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
$route['404_override'] = 'Home';`

Answer (score 1):

Try This--

Please put in **application->config->routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

Comment: Thanks @SAVe. I mentioned above as well that the routes.php contains `$route['default_controller'] = 'Home'; $route['404_override'] = 'Home';`.  Any 404 is redirecting to the home page, but the 404 page remains in the url (eg. /v32, /v100, anything). I can't find where it would be noted to not remove when redirecting.

Comment: If you want to get rid of the wrong url you could make a new controller (or method in 'home' controller) and in it just redirect with `header()` func to 'home' that way any suffix will go away. This is because if you only set it in the routes file it doesn't redirect, it just loads the `home` controller instead of the 404 page.